# Twitching objects in Unity during camera movement in 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, 2d, rendering, transform

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate (SP1),
Unity 5.3.2 (also tested with 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.2.4).

I've caused a bug which is visible in editor, standalone builds, Android builds.

Simple sceene contains:
 **Sphere** - GameObject *without* sphere colider and *with* Rigidbody2D which is used by movement script:

```
private Rigidbody2D m_rigidbody;

void Start() {
    m_rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) //RIGHT
    {
        m_rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(1, 0);
    } else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) //LEFT
    {
        m_rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(-1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        m_rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**3 Cubes** - static GameObjects (for abillity to see that sphere is moving)
**MainCamera**  - classic camera, that follows shere using CS script:

```
public Transform m_Target;

void Update () {
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(m_Target.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), 1f);
}
```

### **Problem:** while camera moves, we can see, that (static) GameObjects are "twitching" on the screen...

I've used FixedUpdate in scripts(didn't solve the problem).

Used different Interpolate settings: even used on both (sphere and camera) kinematic Rigidbody2D Extrapolate setting (didn't solve the problem).

Tried to use Rigidbody (instead os Rigidbody2D).

I've found similar question [Link to unity3d.ru forum](http://www.unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5713&st=0&sk=t&sd=a)

(didn't solve the problem)

***Update:*** I've set a movement script to Camera and turned off "camera follow". Just simple standart camera moving right (or left) with constant speed and result - static objects are twitching...

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(m_Target.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), 1f);
```

...your interpolant factor is 1f. That would just make it jump directly to the target value rather than *lerping* it. I suggest changing that to something else, like 0.75f. That is,

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(m_Target.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), 0.75f);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for a respond, but the problem is in twitching objects, while camera moves